# Listening for and injecting paste operations cross platform

Tags: java, javafx, copy-paste

## Primary Question

I'd like to intercept paste operations into my JavaFX app (in a HTMLEditor specifically) to I can sanitize what a user can enter.  Right now I'm able to intercept the command in windows using the following:

```
//In the initalize method of an HTMLEditor
super.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
    if(e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == KeyCode.V) {
        modifyClipboardForNextPaste();
    }
});
```

But the paste command for OSX is "command + v" so this does not pick up those commands. Is there some type of filter I can add that picks up the paste event itself and not the keys that may or may not be bound to the paste event on the OS?

## Related question:

I'm also trying to inject the paste command when a user selects a paste option on a context menu I'm making using the following code:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

This has the same issue as above where OSX user or users who modified their paste commands do not get this.

Comment: Note that [`KeyEvent.isShortcutDown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#isShortcutDown--) will capture control on windows and cmd on OSX; however you are correct that intercepting a semantic "paste" command is better. For text input controls, you can simply override [`paste()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#paste--) or (better) use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) with a filter; afaik there is no equivalent in `HTMLEditor`.

Comment: @James_D thanks for the input, I'm going to go with the isShortcutDown() and I'll add the meta to the paste command if the host OS is mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments  above have already answered the question. I am adding the actual code as a convenience here:

```java
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public void enablePaste() {
  super.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
    if(e.isShortcutDown() && e.getCode() == KeyCode.V) {
      Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
      // your action here e.g.      
      // if (clipboard.hasUrl()) {
      //  
      //}
    }
  });
}
```